# If you include a file in PHP within a loop will it access the file every time it runs in the loop?

Tags: php, file, loops, include

If you have this

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) include('whatever.php');
```

Will it pull the file ten actual times, or will it only access the file once, and keep its contents and simply evaluate it for the other 9 times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will include the file ten times.

If that's a problem, you could use `include_once`

Comment: If I put include_once in a for loop wont it just include it once and then display nothing for the other 9 times?

Comment: Well, yeah :P Sometimes you *want* it to include ten times, sometimes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough to check - put a sleep() in there, have the file do some output, and during one of the sleep periods, modify the file to change its output.

whatever.php:

```
<?php 

echo 'hello from version 1.0';
sleep(10);
```

then during one of the sleeps, change it to "version 2.0" using another shell. If the output doesn't change, then PHP has loaded the file ONCE and cached it - you'll still get 10 copies of the file's output/effects, but you'll know that PHP didn't hit the disk 10 times.

Comment: Good way to determine the behaviour of the include method in PHP, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if the file is going to be cashed and included from memory instead of parsed and compiled to PHP bytecode again and again: -Yes, you will process the same file n times if you include that given file n times. This is the standard PHP behavior but...

You can change that (and it seems to me that you're looking for that?). As I said, **PHP will include the file the first time and will not cache it for you**... unless you're using any PHP caching module like APC:

When using [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apc.php), things are going to be different, the outputted result will be the same but the server behavior will change a lot! The first time you include a file it will be parsed, compiled into PHP bytecode (machine readable instructions) and will get stored in a shared memory. Later, unless that given file gets modified, it will **NOT** be processed again! PHP will go straight to the pre-compiled version of your program and execute it, saving you a lot of time and resources! Good for high traffic web applications.

More about APC [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator)