# include inside a loop

Tags: php, loops, include

i have a function , which reads values stored in an external file like so

```
function MyFunction($param) {
include ($MyInclude);
...do the job
}
```

i am calling this function for every instance of a loop

```
foreach ($fileArray as $param => $processed) {
MyFunction($param);
...rest of the job
}
```

do i overload the servers memory , or does the file load just once and read from cache ? Do i need to fix this ? I am asking because the "$fileArray" will grow over time processing more and more files.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [If you include a file in PHP within a loop will it access the file every time it runs in the loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7934819/1409082)

Comment: Why to include in every iteration, if $MyInclude is not parametr-based ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include` will always "copy" the contents of those file as if they were typed in there. If you have definitions in those files that might even result in errors.

If you just have some variable literals in that file, then it probably won't create errors but the memory usage is depends on what you do with those. If you just include inside the function and don't return any of them or copy them into other external variables or such, they will be garbage collected when the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

It'll include it every time, which will cause errors if you have definitions (as it'll try to redefine somethings). Try `include_once` instead or refactor your function so it doesn't need to `include` on every iteration (which is better, I'd say).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to include a file inside a function, especially multiple times. If you need to do this, you can use require_once instead of include.

However I suggest you include it once outside the function. And then use any variables you need as globals.